# clearInterval() is not working when called more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, toggle

I am building a React App and I have implemented a slider in my app. By default my slider is automatically but I made a toggle button so the user can stop the automatization at any tine.

Of course I ușe `setInterval` to make this auto-sliding effect. When I press the toggle first time it stops, but when I start it again and try to stop it another time it doesn't work and the auto-sliding continues when it should stop.

This is my code:

```
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle-container");
const toggleDot = document.querySelector(".toggle");
let autoSliding = true;

let slidingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    nextButton.click();
}, 2500);

const stopAutoSliding = () => {
    toggleDot.style.left = "10%";
    toggle.style.background = "#ccc";
    autoSliding = false;

    clearInterval(slidingInterval);
}

const restartAutoSliding = () => {
    toggleDot.style.left = "calc(90% - 20px)";
    toggle.style.background = "#0c46b3";
    autoSliding = true;
    let slidingInterval = setInterval(() => {
        nextButton.click()
    }, 2500);
}

toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (autoSliding) {
        stopAutoSliding();
    } else {
        restartAutoSliding();
    }
});
```

`nextButton` is just a button for which I set an `addEventListener` method for `click` events and it just simply makes the slider to move to the next slide.

If you wanna see it working follow this [link](https://acs-sporting.alinpeter.repl.co).

Comment: I don't see anything related to React here.  But if this code is executing inside a component and being re-invoked when the component re-renders then you could be creating multiple intervals, and only "stopping" the last one.

Comment: @David Yeah... You cannot see anything about React but it is from a `js` file that contains the logic for the slider only. This file is imported in the `Carousel` component and the the component is rendered in the App

Comment: The behavior strongly suggests that you are creating multiple intervals.  You'll want to ensure that you are clearing your intervals before creating any new ones.  How you'd accomplish this depends on how you are invoking this code in the first place.

Comment: @David I think that the fact that I am using the `let` keyword creates a new interval.